# Ruby whiltelists in whitelists

Tags: ruby

I know we can iterate over whitelist parameters in Ruby like the following way:

```
%i( name ).each do |entry|
  puts entry
end
```

I'm curious if there is any possibility of iterating on a whiltelist which has entries of whitelists.

```
%i( %i( name,surname ), %i( startDate, endDate ) ) .each do | entry |
  entry.each do |e|
   puts e
  end
end
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The `%i()` is a helper for defining arrays of symbols. So this

```
%i(foo bar)
```

is equivalent to this (the "full" form)

```
[:foo, :bar]
```

Note how each element in the first line is becoming a symbol. It doesn't make much sense to put something there something other than words (such as nested `%i` arrays).

Comment: Let's see if this is enough hint for you to fix your nested array definition.

Answer (score 0):

There is also `Array#flatten` method, quite useful for recursive arrays:

```
[ %i(name surname), %i(startDate endDate) ].flatten.each { |e| puts e }
```